# Trouble with replacing Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am learning about Fragments and I am having some trouble with the transaction.replace method. My sample app has 2 fragments. A a list fragments and a details fragment. They are supposed to work like to you would expect them to, you tap on an item on the list and it shows up in the details fragment. This works perfectly fine in the dual pane format where the fragments are side by side and the details fragment is updated when I tap on a new list item.Like so: 
[image: Dual pane format]
I am having trouble with in the single place view where the details fragment is to replace the list fragment. This is not happening, the details fragment is getting overlayed  on the list fragment. I am using the transaction.replace().Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Here is (what I think are the relevant) bits of code. Let me know if you need to see any more of the code.

```
void showNote(long id){


    EditNoteFragment newNote = new EditNoteFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong("RowId", id);
    newNote.setArguments(args);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if(mDualPane)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "in double  pane" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        transaction.replace(R.id.edit_note_fragment, newNote);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "in single  pane" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        transaction.replace(R.id.notes_list_fragment, newNote);
        Fragment oldFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.notes_list_fragment);
        if(oldFragment != null)
            transaction.remove(oldFragment);


    }

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();


}
```

the layout/main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false">

 <fragment android:name="drkstr.yan.NotesListFragment"
          android:id="@+id/notes_list_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

The Layout-land/main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false">

 <fragment android:name="drkstr.yan.NotesListFragment"
          android:id="@+id/notes_list_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <fragment android:name="drkstr.yan.EditNoteFragment"
          android:id="@+id/edit_note_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />


  </LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
cheers

Comment: Try to remove "Fragment oldFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.notes_list_fragment);
        if(oldFragment != null)
            transaction.remove(oldFragment);"

Comment: If you're planing to do transactions with fragments then you can't embed them in the xml layout like you did. So you'll need to add those fragments in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding fragment in layout, you can just add the containers there(say, a frame layout).
Then do the transactions in the code.
ie,

```
transaction.replace(<container_id>, newNote);
```

In doing so you can avoid using these code-

```
 Fragment oldFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.notes_list_fragment);
        if(oldFragment != null)
            transaction.remove(oldFragment);
```

Comment: There is a mistake in removing the fragment by id, you can use findFragmentByTag() instead of findFragmentById() ,after adding fragments with appropriate tags in your existing code,and check how it behaves then.(Out of curiosity,Have not checked this.)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in your `transaction.replace(...)` method. The first argument is layout container that you want to attach your new fragment to, not the old fragment that you want to replace. So try calling it with:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.container, newNote);
```

But first, add `R.id.container` to your outter layout in main_activity.xml